# installing deployer,org on windows

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to deploy laravel application using deployer.org. The setup process works fine at my home on mac computer. But while I am trying to setup deployer on windows I am facing some error.

While running the following command
     mv deployer.phar /usr/local/bin/dep

I get the following message
    mv: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/bin/dep': No such file or
    directory it seems /usr/local/bin/dep does not exist.

What will the right location on Windows

[Deployer Documentation](https://deployer.org/docs/installation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path : `/usr/local/bin` is for **Mac** or **Linux** OS

For windows : You can copy your file to any location. But you will have to create a environment variable with the name deployer so that you can call deployer from any location in windows.

Refer this link

https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: If it worked for you, can you please accept it as answer ?

Comment: Did. Thanks a lot.